# How to crop a byte[] array containing Y' (luma) without converting to Bitmap

Tags: android, arrays, image-processing, android-camera2, yuv

EDIT: Solved! See below.
I need to crop my image (YUV422888 color space) which I obtain from the onImageAvailable listener of Camera2. I don't want or need to convert it to Bitmap as it affects performance a lot, and also I'm actually interested in luma and not in RGB information (which is contained in Plane 0 of the Image).
I came up with the following solution:

1. Get the Y' information contained in the Plane 0 of the Image object made available by Camera2 in the listener.
2. Convert the Y' Plane into a byte[] array **in**.
3. Convert the byte[] array to a 2d byte[][] array in order to crop.
4. Use some **for** loops to crop at desired left, right, top and bottom coordinates.
5. Fold the 2d byte[][] array back to a 1d byte[] array **out**, containing cropped luma Y' information.

Point 4 unfortunately yields a corrupt image. **What am I doing wrong?**

In the **onImageAvailableListener** of Camera2 (please note that although I am computing a bitmap, it's only to see what's happening, as I'm not interested in the Bitmap/RGB data):

```
               Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
               ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer(); // Grab just the Y' Plane.
               buffer.rewind();
               byte[] data = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
               buffer.get(data);

               Bitmap bitmap = cropByteArray(data, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()); // Just for preview/sanity check purposes. The bitmap is **corrupt**.

               runOnUiThread(new bitmapRunnable(bitmap) {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       image_view_preview.setImageBitmap(this.bitmap);
                   }
               });
```

The **cropByteArray** function needs fixing. It outputs a bitmap that is corrupt, and should output an **out** byte[] array similar to **in**, but containing only the cropped area:

```
    public Bitmap cropByteArray(byte[] in, int inw, int inh) {

    int l = 100; // left crop start
    int r = 400; // right crop end
    int t = 400; // top crop start
    int b = 700; // top crop end
    int outw = r-l;
    int outh = b-t;


    byte[][] in2d = new byte[inw][inh]; // input width and height are 1080 x 1920.
    byte[] out = new byte[outw*outh];
    int[] pixels = new int[outw*outh];

    i = 0;
    for(int col = 0; col < inw; col++) {
        for(int row = 0; row < inh; row++) {
            in2d[col][row] = in[i++];
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    for(int col = l; col < r; col++) {
        for(int row = t; row < b; row++) {
            //out[i++] = in2d[col][row]; // out is the desired output of the function, but for now we output a bitmap instead

            int grey = in2d[col][row] & 0xff;
            pixels[i++] = 0xFF000000 | (grey * 0x00010101);

        }
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, inw, inh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

**EDIT** Solved thanks to the suggestion by Eddy Talvala. The following code will yield the Y' (luma plane 0 from ImageReader) cropped to the desired coordinates. The cropped data is in the **out** byte array. The bitmap is generated just for confirmation. I am also attaching the handy YUVtoGrayscale() function below.

```
        Image.Plane[] planes    = image.getPlanes();
        ByteBuffer buffer       = planes[0].getBuffer();
        int stride              = planes[0].getRowStride();
        buffer.rewind();
        byte[] Y = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(Y);

        int t=200; int l=600;
        int out_h = 600; int out_w = 600;
        byte[] out = new byte[out_w*out_h];

        int firstRowOffset = stride * t + l;
        for (int row = 0; row < out_h; row++) {
            buffer.position(firstRowOffset + row * stride);
            buffer.get(out, row * out_w, out_w);
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = YUVtoGrayscale(out, out_w, out_h);
```

Here goes the **YUVtoGrayscale()**.

```
    public Bitmap YUVtoGrayscale(byte[] yuv, int width, int height) {

    int[] pixels = new int[yuv.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < yuv.length; i++) {
        int grey = yuv[i] & 0xff;
        pixels[i] = 0xFF000000 | (grey * 0x00010101);
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

There are some remaining issues. I am using the front camera and although the preview orientation is correct inside the TextureView, the image returned by ImageViewer is rotated clockwise and flipped vertically (a person is lying on their right cheek in the preview, only the right cheek is the left cheek because of the vertical flip) on my device which has sensor orientation of 270 deg. **Is there an accepted solution to have both the preview and saved photos in the same, correct orientation using Camera2?**

Cheers.

Comment: The edited answer give me a BufferUnderflowException in the buffer.get(x) line. Any idea?

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be helpful if you described how the image is corrupt - do you see a valid image but it's distorted, or is it just total garbage, or just total black?

But I'm guessing you're not paying attention to the row stride of the Y plane (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.Plane.html#getRowStride() ), which would typically result in an image that's skewed (vertical lines become angled lines).

When accessing the Y plane, the byte index of pixel (x,y) is:

```
y * rowStride + x
```

not

```
y * width + x
```

because row stride may be larger than width.

I'd also avoid copying so much; you really don't need the 2D array, and a large byte[] for the image also wastes memory.

You can instead seek() to the start of each output row, and then only read the bytes you need to copy straight into your destination byte[] out with ByteBuffer.get(byte[], offset, length).

That'd look something like

```
int stride = planes[0].getRowStride();
ByteBuffer img = planes[0].getBuffer();
int firstRowOffset = stride * t + l;
for (int row = 0; row < outh; row++) {
    img.position(firstRowOffset + row * stride);
    img.get(out, row * outw, outw);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion helped me solve it. I am editing my question with the solution and marking your answer accepted :)

Comment: One note on your edited solution - you can remove the whole 'byte[] Y' array, since you don't use it at all. And save a decent bit of memory.